# How to compare LocalDateTime objects?

Tags: java, jodatime

How can I compare two `LocalDateTime` objects of `joda` by date only?

`DateTimeComparator.getDateOnlyInstance().compare(ldt1, ldt2) == 0`

gives this exception:

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No instant converter found for type: org.joda.time.LocalDate`

Comment: try to use .equals()

Answer (score 4):

How about

```
ldt1.toLocalDate().equals(ldt2.toLocalDate())
```